# SIGNAL is not emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

I have issue with SIGNAL not being emitted. Here is minimal example of this issue:

main.cpp - standard main

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "combobox.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    combobox combo_box;
    mainLayout->addWidget(combo_box.box);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

combobox.h

```
#ifndef COMBOBOX_H
#define COMBOBOX_H

#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>

class combobox : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    combobox();
    ~combobox();

    QComboBox *box = new QComboBox;

public slots:
    void selection_changed();
};

#endif // COMBOBOX_H
```

combobox.cpp

```
#include "combobox.h"

combobox::combobox()
{
    QString string = "test 1";
    box->addItem(string);
    string = "test 2";
    box->addItem(string);
    box->setCurrentIndex(0);
    connect(box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(selection_changed()));
}

combobox::~combobox()
{

}

void combobox::selection_changed()
{
    qDebug() << "Selection changed";
    box->setCurrentIndex(-1);
}
```

You need to run qmake before compiling.

When I run this program and change combobox index selection_changed is not executed. Why?

SIGNAL and SLOT connection definitely works, because if I add box->setCurrentIndex(1); at the end of combobox constructor, selection_changed will be executed once.

I am using QT 5.4 with QT Creator

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the return from the connect statement. Also, run this in the debugger, put a breakpoint on the connect and check the Application Output window when stepping over the connect line, to ensure that the connection is made correctly. Finally, use the [Qt 5 connection syntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), which will verify the connection during compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem because of you create your `ComboBox` class object at stack. So if you write some debug information at destructor of this class you can see object destroyed immediately after `MainWindow` constructor out of scope:

```
ComboBox::~ComboBox()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);


    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    ComboBox combo_box;
    mainLayout->addWidget(combo_box.box);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
}
```

And `qDebug()` got the following result:

> MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)
>
> virtual ComboBox::~ComboBox()

Thats why signal don't emitted. So you need create object on the heap or make something tricks.

**Also**, you have dynamically allocated object `*box` at your `ComboBox` class and don't specify parent of this object, so it seems memory leak is possible. Specify parent or delete object at destructor of `ComboBox` class.